# Duplicate Symbols integrating ASOAnimatedButton

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Installing the `ASOAnimatedButton` CocoPod control with `-all_load` flag set in XCode's Build Setting --> "Other Linker Flag" creates 20 duplicate symbols.

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ASOTwoStateButton in:
    /Users/phamdacloc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HealthChron-cvyzecsyxjjbjddagxxmtcjushal/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(ASOTwoStateButton-B710713467C732B5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ASOTwoStateButton in:
    /Users/phamdacloc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HealthChron-cvyzecsyxjjbjddagxxmtcjushal/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(ASOTwoStateButton-B710713467C732B5.o)
ld: 20 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have to set -all_load flag because i'm integrating with Google's Picasa service. Does anyone know how to resolve `ASOAnimatedButton` duplicate symbol?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve my problem by uninstalling this control from Pod. I then manually added the files from `Classes/iOS/` to my project and things working again.

Answer (score 0):

You can install all ASOAnimatedButton's subspec individually to avoid duplicate symbols by specifying below lines in your Podfile.

```
pod 'ASOAnimatedButton/TwoStateButton'
pod 'ASOAnimatedButton/BounceButton'
```